# SQL Join table from 1 of 2 different tables optimized search

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, query-optimization

As a simplification, I have four tables, book, publisher, author, and company.  Both book and publisher have a reference to author, *but that reference can be null*.

I can find the author by joining the author table using an OR join query like this, but it is incredibly slow.

*edit* I have to use the author table to join another.

Schema:

[image: schema design]

`select book.title,
         author.name,
         company.name as company_name
          from book
           inner join publisher on book.publisher_id = publisher.id
           inner join author 
             on (book.author_id = author.id OR publisher.author_id = author.id)
           inner join company on author.company_id = company.id;`

I am wondering what the best way to optimize this query would be, instead of joining on an OR conditional. Thanks

Comment: Please add your table structure (as text) in the question

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  `OR` in the `ON` clause can really slow down a query.

Instead, use two `left join`s:

```
select b.title, coalesce(ab.name, ap.name) as name
from book b inner join
     publisher p
     on b.publisher_id = p.id left join
     author ab
     on b.author_id = ab.id left join
     author ap
     on p.author_id = ap.id;
```

Formally, you might need to add `where ab.id is not null or ap.id is not null` if you only want to return rows with a match in one of the tables.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I updated the question, as I have to actually use that author table to join another table